# Tracking on/off state in a sequence

Tags: python, generator

I have a generator function that tracks whether I am between a certain pair of events-- a "start" event and an "end" event. For example, it could be examining tokens and reporting whether I am between the comment delimiters `"/*"` and `"*/"` (non-nesting). The following code works, but is there a nice itertools combination or logical restructuring that would simplify it (and/or make it more "pythonic")?

```
def tokspan(starttok, endtok, stream):
    inside = False
    for tok in stream:
        if (not inside) and tok == starttok:
            inside = True
        yield (inside, tok)
        if inside and tok == endtok:
            inside = False          

tstream = "int x; /* a non-nesting comment /* etc. */ x=1; main();".split()          
for status, tok in tokspan("/*", "*/", tstream):
    print(status, tok)
```

The above (intentionally) returns `True` for the boundary tokens (`/*` and `*/`), but that's not particularly important. If you have an approach that happens to exclude one or both boundaries (like python ranges do), I'd still like to know about it.

Comment: You _could_ do `inside = (inside or tok == starttok) and tok != endtok` before the `yield`, but I guess that doesn't really help much.

Comment: FWIW, to my eye this actually reads quite nicely.

Comment: @PM, I'll think about it, thanks. It's more compact but doesn't exactly enhance readability...

Comment: @NPE, thanks... it's the best I could do but I wonder if I'm missing some itertools magic, or some such.

Comment: No worries, alexis. I actually agree with NPE that your original version is fine. And it's certainly more readable than mine. And I doubt mine is more efficient than yours but I'm feeling too lazy to run a timeit test. :)

Comment: Just leave out the test for `inside`, it does not change the result.

Comment: @Jochen, you are right! Well spotted. It's left over because it made a difference in the more general case I distilled this question from.

Answer (score 1):

The only simplification that I can think of is rewriting the logic around setting/resetting `inside`:

```
def tokspan(starttok, endtok, stream):
    inside = False
    for tok in stream:
        inside |= (tok == starttok)
        yield (inside, tok)
        inside &= (tok != endtok)
```

Whether this makes the code more or less readable is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Now why didn't _I_ think of using bitwise operators with booleans? :) Nice work, NPE. I reckon it's just as readable as the original (if not moreso), but as you say readability of such things is in the eye of the beholder.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to use a decorator over here. I am not sure if this is going to be useful to you or not but this might just give you some ideas.

Create a decorator which stores the items you want to filter out with:

```
import itertools as it

class insideDec(object):

    def __init__(self, start, stop):

        self.start = start
        self.stop  = stop

    def __call__(self, f):

        def wrapper(x):
            x1 = it.dropwhile(lambda m: not m.startswith(self.start), x  )
            x1.next()
            x2 = it.takewhile(lambda m: not m.startswith(self.stop),  x1 )
            return f(x2)

        return wrapper 

@insideDec('{', '}')
def f(val):
    return val

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ''.join(f('This is some {string that needs to} be printed'))
```

Now you apply the decorator to a function that accepts a string. This will convert the function into one whose input is an iterator. You then process the iterator like you would any other iterator.

Of course, you can always convert the iterator to a string at any point of time (like for example over here):

```
        # rest of the code ...
        x2 = it.takewhile(lambda m: not m.startswith(self.stop),  x1 )
        return f(''.join(x2))
        # rest of the code ...
```

That's really up to you ...

Edit:

Sorry about that. I misread your question. For tokenizing, maybe something like the following might help?

```
class tokenize():

    def __init__(self, strVal, start, stop):
        self.start   = start
        self.stop    = stop
        self.strTees = it.tee(strVal, len(start))
        self.inside  = False
        for i, strTee in enumerate(self.strTees):
            for j in range(i):
                next(strTee, '')
        self.strVals = it.izip( *self.strTees )

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):

        v = ''.join(self.strVals.next())
        if v == '': raise StopIteration
        if v == self.start: self.inside = True
        if v == self.stop:  self.inside = False

        # print '[',v, ']'

        return (v[0], self.inside)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    strVal = 'int x; /* a non-nesting comment etc. */ x=1; main();'
    for x, y in tokenize( strVal, '/*', '*/' ):
        print x, y
```

Again, this is not perfect, by might serve your purposes ...

Here is the output: 
    i False
    n False
    t False
      False
    x False
    ; False
      False
    / True
    * True
      True
    a True
      True
    n True
    o True
    n True
    - True
    n True
    e True
    s True
    t True
    i True
    n True
    g True
      True
    c True
    o True
    m True
    m True
    e True
    n True
    t True
      True
    e True
    t True
    c True
    . True
      True
    * False
    / False
      False
    x False
    = False
    1 False
    ; False
      False
    m False
    a False
    i False
    n False
    ( False
    ) False

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but actually I want to pass through all the tokens-- I guess my comment example set you on the wrong track there. I like the callable class as a way to maintain state, but the function needs to be reusable-- burying the boundary tokens in the decorator is a no-go.

Comment: thanks for your trouble, but I'm not sure I see the advantage in your new solution. I am not even sure I quite follow it:  you are iterating over individual characters, which you fork into parallel iterators and then reassemble with `izip` so you can examine the ngrams-- why go to all this trouble?

Comment: The main reason who I did it this way is because in your example a comment like `int a =/*This is some comment*/25;`, splitting this string will not give you the tokens. Furthermore, the problem with iterators is that `beginswith` no longer works once you convert a string into an iterator. So although, you can check ngrams single character long with `beginswith`, you can no longer do that with multiple character ngrams. Hence the `tee`-`izip` hack.

Comment: This will serialise the input, but will only peek at `n` characters at a time. This way, you can serialise the entire file into the function without worrying about memory issues.

Comment: Tokenization is a separate problem (which I don't have and didn't ask about), and iterating character by character is _not_ a good way to approach it. If you need better tokenization, make a tokenizer. It can be done in one line with `re.split()`. By the way, your sliding ngrams will think that '/*/' is a complete comment.

Comment: Actually that is true, I didnt think about that!